# How to query mongodb collection similar to "NOT IN" with list of value returned from subquery

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongoDB, using version 2.6.4. I got stuck with writing mongo query and looking for expert's help here.

I have following sample documents in myCollection:

```
{   msgID: "1011",
    journalID: 1,   
    status: "FLAGGED",
    timeSent: ISODate("2015-10-27T03:44:19.359Z") },

{   msgID: "1012",
    journalID: 1,   
    status: "FLAGGED",
    timeSent: ISODate("2015-10-28T07:12:03.446Z") },

{   msgID: "1012",
    journalID: 2,   
    status: "INITIATED",
    timeReceived: ISODate("2015-10-28T08:06:21.221Z") },

{   msgID: "1013",
    journalID: 1,   
    status: "FLAGGED",
    timeSent: ISODate("2015-10-28T13:21:13.568Z") },

{   msgID: "1013",
    journalID: 2,   
    status: "INITIATED",
    timeReceived: ISODate("2015-10-28T13:56:06.419Z") },

{   msgID: "1013",
    journalID: 3,   
    status: "CLOSED",
    timeReceived: ISODate("2015-10-28T16:11:38.875Z") },

{   msgID: "1014",
    journalID: 1,   
    status: "FLAGGED",
    timeSent: ISODate("2015-10-29T13:21:13.568Z") },

{   msgID: "1015",
    journalID: 1,   
    status: "FLAGGED",
    timeSent: ISODate("2015-10-28T08:26:57.828Z") },

{   msgID: "1016",
    journalID: 1,   
    status: "FLAGGED",
    timeSent: ISODate("2015-10-28T11:03:09.075Z") },

{   msgID: "1016",
    journalID: 2,   
    status: "CLOSED",
    timeReceived: ISODate("2015-10-28T14:19:19.907Z") }
```

How to write mongo query that will fetch documents from myCollection satisfying following condition:

- Return all msgID which only has record with FLAGGED state (i.e.
  exclude those msgID that has entry either with INITIATED or CLOSED
  state).
- And where timeSent < 29th Oct 2015

**Expected result would be:**

```
msgID     status        timeSent
-----     ---------     -----------------------------------
1011      FLAGGED       ISODate("2015-10-27T03:44:19.359Z")
1015      FLAGGED       ISODate("2015-10-28T08:26:57.828Z")
```

I know in SQL this can be achieved by below query:

```
SELECT  m1.msgID, m1.status, m1.timeSent
FROM    myCollection m1
WHERE   m1.msgID NOT IN
            ( SELECT m2.msgID FROM myCollection m2 WHERE m2.status IN ('INITIATED', 'CLOSED'))
AND     m1.status = "FLAGGED"
AND     m1.timeSent < "10-29-2015 00:00:00"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: More to the point should be if you look at and understand the SQL query given here the sub-query is not even required and the real query need only look for status "FLAGGED" and the time within the range. So the lesson here is don't try to reproduce the actions of poorly written SQL, but just solve the problem of data selection instead.

Comment: one msgID can have multiple records with state as 'FLAGGED', 'INITIATED', 'CLOSED' ..... and so on. I don't want those msgID that have any records with 'INITIATED' or 'CLOSED', and hence this subquery to filter out those msgID.

Comment: A sub-query is basically a "join" and MongoDB does not perform joins in any way. It's not a great design to begin with, since the current SQL just looks for and excludes **all** documents/records that match the exluded values. The logical premise is "FLAGGED" comes first, so anything with more that one state should be excluded. It would probably be better to model this with an "array" of "state" changes, rather than separate objects in the collection. The query becomes very simple then.

Comment: @Blakes Seven  Agree with you, I need to change the model to capture journal details at array level for each msgID. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like [@BlakesSeven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5031275/blakes-seven) mentioned, it would be better to change the schema. Instead of adding a document for each status, you should group your items per `msgID` and add the items in an array. The first three documents will look like this:

```
{
    msgID: "1011",
    items: [{
        journalID: 1,   
        status: "FLAGGED",
        timeSent: ISODate("2015-10-27T03:44:19.359Z")
    }]
},
{
    msgID: "1012",
    items: [{
        journalID: 1,   
        status: "FLAGGED",
        timeSent: ISODate("2015-10-28T07:12:03.446Z")
    }, {
        journalID: 2,   
        status: "INITIATED",
        timeReceived: ISODate("2015-10-28T08:06:21.221Z")
    }]
}
```

This allows you to make better queries with a better performance. Your query will look like this:

```
db.getCollection('someCollection').find({
    items: {
        $size : 1
    },
    'items.status': 'FLAGGED'
});
```

Comment: I like it. NoSQL design made simple.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: For the record, my previous comments are all deleted as it does not add to the current state of the answer ( which is really good ) and that is the example people really should be following.

Comment: @ThomasBormans  Perfect!! Thank you so much for your guidance. I'll work on schema changes following this simple NoSQL design.

Answer (score 1):

Though its not optimized from performance point and I understand schema changes required for storing and retrieving such kind of data, but just to share with all, I could figure out the query based on given data structure:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate(
    { $group: {
      _id: "$msgID", stateChange: { $push: { status: "$status", timeSent: "$timeSent" }}}
    },
    { $match: {
        "stateChange.status": { $eq: 'FLAGGED', $nin: ['INITIATED','CLOSED'] }, 
        "stateChange.timeSent": { $lt: ISODate("2015-10-29T00:00:00")}}
    },
    { $unwind: "$stateChange" },
    { $project: {
        _id: 0, msgID: "$_id", status: "$stateChange.status", timeSent: "$stateChange.timeSent"}
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using **find()**

```
db.collection.find(query, projection)
```

> query - Specifies selection criteria (optional) [more](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/)  (WHERE Clause in SQL)
>   projection - all fields in the matching document (optional)

According to your problem can be solved as following

```
  db.flagged.find({
        status: 'FLAGGED',
        timeSent: {
            $lt: ISODate('2015-10-29T00:00:00')
        },
        {msgID:1,status:1,timeSent:1}
    });
```

More details following [Mongdb Tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)